# get value from pandas segment and subtract in place

Tags: python, pandas

i have a table with values similar to

```
val1     val2     val3    segVal
  0      12.3     88.2
 20         0        0
 50      14.5     88.7
 70         0        0
 85         0        0
 90      18.2     88.9
```

for my segVal, i need to use the differences from my val1 columns where val2 is known. so my first segment would be zero to 50, i'm subtracting from 0 and applying that to all segVal rows. my next segment is at 90 so i would subtract that from 50 and apply that.

So my output table would be

```
val1     val2     val3    segVal
  0      12.3     88.2     50
 20        0         0     50
 50      14.5     88.7     50
 70         0        0     40
 85         0        0     40
 90      18.2     88.9     40
```

my current somewhat working method is

```
df1 = df[df.val2 != 0]
df1 = df1.copy()
df1.segVal=(df1['val1'].diff(-1))*1
```

so i'm creating a additional df and calculating the values this way, then merging back the values with the original df.

It seems there has got to be a better way to do this, I mean, my method works, but doesn't' seem too efficient creating additional df's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
df['segVal'] = df.where(df.val2.ne(0)).val1.dropna().diff().reindex(df.index).bfill()

   val1  val2  val3  segVal
0  0     12.3  88.2  50.0  
1  20    0.0   0.0   50.0  
2  50    14.5  88.7  50.0  
3  70    0.0   0.0   40.0  
4  85    0.0   0.0   40.0  
5  90    18.2  88.9  40.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much,  i knew there was a cleaner and better way.